# Byte operations c#

Tags: c#, byte, operation, threshold

I have an expression which is supposed to calculate the threshold. The original code was:

```
float threshold = vertHist.min + ((vertHist.max - vertHist.min)/2);
```

but was then modifies to:

```
retVal.threshold = (byte)(minValue + ((maxValue - minValue) >> 1));
```

I can understand the original code and the logic behind it, but can someone kindly walk me through the latter code, which is a revised version of the former?

Thanks.

Comment: `>>1` means shift right by 1, which is the same as divide by 2 on a two's complement unsigned integral data type. The new code should use `/2` instead so that it can be understood. If one of my team checked this code in to my codebase, it would prompt a very harsh code review!

Comment: Thank you. This sums up the answer nicely. Why didn't you submit this as an answer?

Comment: It's very important to note that it only works that way with integers (`long`, `int`, `short`, `byte`). Noting that the original value was assigned to a `float`, it makes me wonder about the validity of the equation. I will say, it is an extremely unnecessary optimization to make to do that, and it is one that will certainly be done for you by the compiler. Beyond that, the rest of the equation is the same.

Comment: @Nate Because I wasn't sure if you needed help on the casting. And I also don't know what issues surround the ranges of the data types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`>>` is the bitwise right shift operator. For positive integers (which you're expecting `maxValue - minValue` to be) it has the effect of dividing by (a power of) 2, and compilers will in fact sometimes replace a division by two with a right shift for you, so you should avoid replacing a division with a shift unless you specifically require shift behaviour.